# Изменение URL без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript

Здравствуете. Наткнулся в инсте на изменение URL, но перезагрузка страницы не происходит. Если скопировать URL в другое окно но инфа тоже загружается.

Полагаю это как то так происходит: при клике по ссылке, отменяю действие по умолчанию копирую ее `href` в `location.hash`, а инфу подгружаю `ajax'ом`, а если браузер пользователя не поддерживает `location.hash`, то просто не отменяю действие по умолчанию при клике на ссылке, и человек по ней переходит.

Это предположение имеет место быть? или есть более лаконичные варианты?

Comment: window.history.pushState({}, 'title', '/some') ввидите в консоле. Читайте о html5 history

Comment: @OlmerDale И если браузер это не поддерживает по получается просто переходим по ссылке?

Comment: Этого я не знаю, я не работаю с такими браузерами.

Comment: Они меняют адрес функцией, которую указал OlmerDale. Ну а всё остальное да, как вы написали

Comment: @JarryRoxwell , если браузер не поддерживает манипуляции с history, то он выкинет js-ошибку.

Comment: инстаграмм написан на ректе. там не парились с роутингом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="link-group">
    <a class="route" href="/orange">orange</a>
    <a class="route" href="/tomato">tomato</a>
</div>
<script>
    document.body.querySelectorAll('.route')
        .forEach( link => link.addEventListener('click', link_clickHandler) );

    function link_clickHandler( event ){
        event.preventDefault();

        let path = event.target.href;

        window.history.pushState({route: path}, "some title", path);
    }

    window.addEventListener('popstate', window_popStateHandler);

    function window_popStateHandler( event ){
        if(event.state){
            console.log(event.state)
        }

        console.log(event);
    }
</script>
```

Вот минимальный код который требуется для создания клиентского роутера. К сожаления в родной для SO песочнице он не будет работать, да и в браузере если подгружать из локального фала, наверное тоже, но с сервером это работает.

Что в коде происходит -

1. все ссылки приводящие к изменению url помечаются классом `route` или любым другим способом.
2. при загрузке js первым делом нужно выбрать все ссылки и подписать их на событие `click`.
3. в обработчике события `click` вызываем `event.preventDefault()` чтобы предотвратить поведение по умолчанию, а именно срабатывание ссылки которое приведет к перезагрузки страницы.
4. с помощью [**History api**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History) помещаем данные о текущем пути и указываем тот самый url который бы мы хотели увидеть в строке состояния. (1)
5. грузим при помощи `ajax` данные и отображаем их.
6. стоит понимать что url хоть и выглядят красиво-как настоящие, то есть без # шеш решетки, на самом деле таковыми не являются. Если Вы зайдя на страницу `http://localhost:8080` измените адрес на `http://localhost:8080/orange`, то все корректно отработает. Но зайдя сразу на адрес `http://localhost:8080/orange` Вы получите ошибку `404`, так как в реальности такого адреса не существует. Для этого нужно чтобы сервер на абсолютно любой запрос всегда отдавал страницу `index.html`. Тогда зайдя на адрес `http://localhost:8080/orange` браузер код клиентского роутера, который в свою очередь распознает url и продолжит работу в штатном режиме, собирая и загружая данные по заданным правилам. Стоит так же понимать что именно клиентский роутер должен показывать страницу `404`, так как только он знает какие пити существуют, а какие нет.
7. ну и стоит добавить что в изоморфном приложение происходит почти все тоже самое за исключением того что при заходе клиентская часть роутера отрабатывает на сервере и в `index.html` помещается уже отрендеренная разметка.

Comment: Сп.бс выручили fanc yoo fannk yoo